# #import "test.h" Vs #import <test.h>

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

What is the difference between importing a header file within "" and within <>?

Like `#import "test.h`" Vs `#import <test.h>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will change the search path for the file. Using <> tells the compiler to look through the system path for the proper file/framework, while using "" tells the compiler that the path is relative to the current file.

For example, `#import <path/to/file.h>` will look through the system paths for the file test.h. The paths include /usr/include and /System/Library/Frameworks, where the first component of the path is treated as the framework to start at. Example paths searched are `/usr/include/path/to/file.h` and `/System/Library/Frameworks/path.framework/Headers/to/file.h`. `#import "path/to/file.h"` will only search the current folder, following the path to find the file, meaning only `./path/to/file.h` is searched.

Comment: I'm going to say this is closest to correct, although you were overly limiting your answer referring to just the Foundation framework.  The Angle brackets will pick up files in any framework included by the project, including user created frameworks.

Comment: @Kendall I didn't say *anything* about the Foundation framework. The one I used in my example is a made up framework named path.

Comment: Hmm, I see, I read the System/Library/Frameworks as pointing to Foundation.  However that part is not quite right, because really the path is pointing only to the Include directory of included frameworks, not /System/Library/Frameworks in general.

Answer (score 1):

" is for a local include, the .h is part of your application. < is for a system include, the .h is part of a installed library.

Answer (score 1):

"" is for local include while the <> for global include

for more info visit this page

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36k2cdd4%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Although technically that's pertinent, it's hard to say how useful this is for an iOS developer where the compiler flags are different than the ones the Microsoft document specifies.